# Ajax responseText returning nothing, but values are present when console.logging the ajax object

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a really simple `ajax` call that is fetching from a `php` file called `functions.php` and for our purposes, `functions.php` is echoing "this worked!". Here is my really simple `ajax` call code:

```
const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "/layout-1/functions.php";
ajax.open("GET", url);
ajax.onload = handleAjax(ajax);
ajax.send()
const response = ajax.response;
console.log(ajax);
console.log(response);
```

And here is the `handleAjax()` function (although not really applicable):

```
function handleAjax(xh) {
    "use strict";
    if (xh.readyState === 4) {
        switch (xh.status) {
        case 401:
            console.log("You are unauthroized to access this");
            break;
        case 403:
            console.log("This is a forbidden asset");
            break;
        case 404:
            console.log("Can't find the asset");
            break;
        case 500:
            console.log("Server failure");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After the above `ajax` call, I'm console.logging two things: the `ajax` object I created and the attribute `response` on that object. In the log of the object, I can see the text "this worked!", but in the log of the variable `response`, I am getting nothing, it is just blank. I have also tried logging `responseText` and the same thing happens, just a blank line in the console.log.
Why is the response present in the object, but when I try to access the response directly, it is blank?

## EDIT:

I don't see how that question applies to mine though, because I'm not getting undefined in my response text, what is happening is the response is returning an empty string, *but the correct response* lives in the `ajax` object. Maybe I missed something in the linked question, but I don't think I did.

Comment: We think you missed something. Read it again and start realizing which calls here are actually async.

Comment: The fact that in your case you get an empty string but in the dup the result is undefined relates to the particular implementation. *The cause is the same.* You need to understand what asynchronous means. (Which is what the dup explains.) You also need to understand that `console.log(ajax)` links to a *live* object, but `response` is the static value of `ajax.response` **at the time it was assigned**.This last sentence is *not* explained in the dup and is what you "missed".